# Unable to bind chrome node with hub

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have below docker-compose.yml file which binds Chrome, Firefox nodes to Hub.

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
  
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT=4444
```

After it binds, i wanted to scale up number of instances by **docker-compose scale chrome=3 firefox=3**.

But when i trigger my suite, i am getting error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Empty pool of VM for setup Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, version: }
Command duration or timeout: 191 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

This is how my RemoteWebDriver routes traffic:

```
if(strBrowsername.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
            {

                try {
                    driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.chrome()));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {

                try {
                    driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox()));
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

**I feel somehow the scaled chrome instances are failing to bind to Hub. How can these scaled up chrome instances bind to Hub?**

Comment: Does anybody have any inputs on the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think i wrote wrong docker-compose.

Below helped:

```
version: "3"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    shm_size: '1gb'
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - 5901:5900
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: selenium-hub
      HUB_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 3
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 3

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    shm_size: '1gb'
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - 5902:5900
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: selenium-hub
      HUB_PORT: 4444
      NODE_MAX_SESSION: 3
      NODE_MAX_INSTANCES: 3
```